# Menu Not Available from WAMP Server 2 Tray Icon on Windows 7 Machine

Tags: wamp

I've downloaded and installed WAMP Server version 2.1d on my Windows 7 machine. When I select "start WAMP Server" from the Start menu, the tray icon appears, but has no functionality. When I hover, the tool tip tells me that 1 of 2 services has started, but the server is offline (which is probably a separate issue). I've run Windows update and installed an optional update for my graphics driver. What else could be preventing the WAMP Server menu from appearing when I right-click the tray icon?

Answer (score 8):

> You may encounter this when setting up a **new PC** or **someone else's PC**.

Attempt one may lead to missing C++ redistributables. I recommend downloading all of them. If you get that issue, you will get some `MSVCR100.dll` file issue.

Attempt two would be reinstalling Wamp again after some weird symptoms. The system tray icon might be broken. Reinstalling won't fix, rabbit hole.

**SOLUTION**

1. Uninstall Wamp
2. Right click the Wamp `install.exe` **RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR**.

Mine is working now.
Mine also popped up a firewall alert which it didnt before, so the admin thing seemed to really kick it along.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem uninstalling WAMP and deleting the folder C:\WAMP, then I installed it again.

Answer (score 4):

Copy the wampmanager.ini file from other wamp installation and restart the wamp. The wamp functions normally.

(or)

http://jcyberinux.com/rjdreyes/wampserver-eparseerror-no-tray-icon-was-specified.html

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue while using WampServer 3.1.3 on my windows10 machines after reinstalling. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling but could not get it working. Then I inspected wampmanager.ini file in my installation and there was the issue in the file it was incomplete. So I borrowed the file from my colleague for whom it was working fine. Replaced the file and restarted WampServer and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem, and my solution is not mentioned in the other answers. So I post it here for reference, in case someone else has the same problem.

I just stumbled over the same problem with Wamp server 3 (64bit) on a Windows 10 machine. Wamp did start, the tray icon appeared, but the menu didn't work.

In my case, I had changed the installation path to C:\Program Files\wamp64. This was the error. I uninstalled wamp and re-installed it with the **default installation path** of C:\wamp64. Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Just Uninstalled and Installed it again, worked for me!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installing on a new machine. I wanted to run WAMP 3.1.7 from D:/wamp64. No menu in the tray and the PHP was not loading. After 3 hours I figured it out. I bought a new SSD external drive and was trying to run it off that. New external SSD was formatted as 'exFAT'. Just reformatted it to NTFS and and viola! Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If the tray icon appears and has white color then your wamp server has began. can also be checked by going to http://localhost.

Anyways i hope you are getting the normal options when you left click on the tray icon. Right clicking the tray icon gives options to change language(which i hope you don't need) , a link to your localhost(can be found at `C:\wamp\scripts\refresh.php`) and a link to [wamp website](http://www.wampserver.com/presentation.php).I am sure no functionality is affected by these options.

Comment: The icon goes from red to orange. I've verified that the server does not start and the localhost page is not available. I don't have any functionality at all when I left click on the tray icon. The menu is inaccessible.

Comment: Mystery solved! As it turns out, I had a prior PHP installation. I dimly recall that when I installed MS Visual Studio on this machine, it gave me the option of choosing support for PHP, so I think that was where it came from. Anyway, after uninstalling WAMP Server and PHP and deleting the directories, I was able to reinstall it successfully. It now appears to be working perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: -1 I have the same issue, and this is not the answer... but @David's comment is.

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the solutions worked, installed all C++ redistributables, uninstalled wamp completely and installed it again, same problem.

At last I figured it out, it seems that `wampmanager.ini` is **incomplete** regarding the tray menu.

### Solution

Open terminal in `c:\wamp64\scripts` and execute :

```
php refresh.php
```

which will **regenerate** `wampmanager.ini` with complete settings.

For me I got the following error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (٢٠٢٣-٠٢-٢٤ ٠١:١٩:٠٥) at position 0 (): Unexpected character in C:\wamp64\scripts\refresh.php on line 168
```

Fixed it by replacing the Arabic date-time string value for `wampStartDate` in `c:\wamp64\wampmanager.conf` `line 19` with an English string.

---

- Windows 10 Pro 22H2
- Wampserver 3.3.0 64bit

Answer (score -1):

What I have tried before:

- I uninstalled and reinstalled WAMP but not works.
- Then I copy the `wampmanager.ini` file from other wamp installation
  and restart the wamp, again not works.

Finally, I found the solution:

**Problem with me is UAC permission. WAMP needs UAC permission to load some menu items.**

So I **turned off UAC**.

How to turn off UAC?

1. Click the Start menu. In the search field type UAC.
2. Click "Change User Account Control settings."
3. In the window that comes up, move the slider down to "Never Notify."
4. Click OK and then restart the computer.

Then restart the WAMP now the menu appears when you click on WAMP tray icon.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGUSj1xRvYE&ab_channel=PratikSayare

Visit https://www.wampserver.com/en/

Goto Download

Click on Download

Check for the link at the bottom under the description Visual Studio 2012: VC 11 vcredist_x64/86.exe
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Visit http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Scroll down and click on the download

Choose the appropriate version and click next.

Open the downloaded file and select the license checkbox, click on Install

Comment: after downloading file from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679, error gone for me