# Not able to launch WAMP - Aestan Tray Menu has stopped working

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I just downloaded and installed WAMP, when I open it I get a  warning box that

> Aestan Tray Menu has stopped working -"A problem has caused program
>   to stop working correctly. Windows will close program and notify you
>   if a solution is found".

I have tried the usual solutions : I checked the IIS and it is already disabled. And I also unchecked the "use port 80..." option in Skype.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 14):

Had the same problem.
I had to install this to make it work properly :

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=29

HTH

Mathieu.

Comment: Thanks! I installed the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336) and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

I was having same problem for latest version of Wampserver (32 bits & PHP 5.4) 2.2E. I had installed and uninstalled many times and different softwares. Also formatted my machine twice. I was stucked for 3-4 days. Probably this way will help someone.

1. Install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29)
2. Install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=8328)
3. Then Install [Wampserver (32 bits & PHP 5.4) 2.2E](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

See for more info:

1. [Aestan Tray Menu Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122679/aestan-tray-menu-error)
2. http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,53095
3. http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,78924

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you download and install the right version of WAMP (32 bit or 64 bit). If you choose the wrong one, apache will die on startup, causing the Aestan tray menu to die.

Answer (score 2):

Mathieu has indeed provided the correct answer.

At least under Windows XP you need to intall:

**Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package**

in order to make it work. You can download it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29

Answer (score 0):

IF problem still occurs after

```
Installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86 or x64 , have to download same version of wamp)
Installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86 or x64 , have to download same version of wamp)
Installing Wampserver (32 bits & PHP 5.4) 2.2E
```

Then remove wamp , install .net framework . Restart your machine , install wamp again.

Also this problem can be solved with the command prompt . Mysql is working when you saw this error but APACHE is failed . So you can start it with command , 
cd c:\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y\bin\
httpd.exe
.You may not see the green light of wamp but you can work over 80.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it properly installed!  I might be the only one who made this mistake, but I followed the advice above and it still didn't work-then I saw that I was downloading the wrong wampserver version  - below the download button on the sourceforge download is a list of files-I pressed the link of the 2.2E file, instead of just clicking the download button on the top of the page

Ellen

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable temporally your Antivirus.

(After a day of trouble I've disabled all Kaspersky activity and everything started to work, also re-enabling Kaspersky....)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no other program conflict Wamp such as IIS, Microsoft Web Deploy, Web Deployment Agent Service, SQL, Skype, Zonealarm, firewall/antivirus, NOD32, Eset, any web related program including Remote Desktop, Teamviewer or Apache, MySQL, PHP outside wamp folder (ie. in Program Files or System32 folder)

Try this: open file httpd.conf through wamp tray icon and find:

```
listen 80
```

Replace with:

```
listen 8181
```

OR

```
Control Panel, Uninstall Programs, Turn Widows Features On or Off, uncheck Internet Information Services
```

to disable IIS sevices from your computer

Answer (score 0):

## at first, install [Microsoft Visual C++ **2008** SP1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582) !

(If WAMP is already installed, then backup **BIN** and **WWW**, and UNINSTALL WAMP, and install that package)!!

( or try [**Visual C++ 2010**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=8328) or [**2012**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) version.. 
in some cases, maybe **.Net Framework** is needed too?))

**After that, install WAMP!**

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the all answers here. But nothing works for me. Problem with me is **UAC permission**. WAMP needs UAC permission to load some menu items.

You need to **turn off UAC permission**.

More info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54514409/6914403

Answer (score 0):

Just do windows10 updates. after update restart computer, then start wampserver64.