# Aestan Tray Menu Error

Tags: wampserver

i installed the wamp server 2.2e in windows xp. when i start the wamp server it displays the windows error(Aestan Tray Menu has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience). Can anyone advise how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 3):

## Before you install Wamp!

If already installed, then UNINSTALL WAMP(you can backup folders **WWW** and BIN>mysql>**data**), and install MS PACKAGES at first:

[Microsoft Visual C++ **2008** SP1 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582) !

 ( or [**2010**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=8328) or [**2012**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) version.. 
in some cases, maybe **.Net Framework** is needed too?))

After that, install WAMP!

Comment: Tried that, did not work. :(

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check:

- Have you installed the services? It can be a little temperamental the tray, but look for an install services batch file. This will get the apache and mysql services running
- Is your configuration OK? Particularly, check apache's config with `httpd -t` on the command line (make sure that you're in the apache/bin folder if httpd isn't in your path)
- Have you got the correct version (32bit versus 64bit)?
- Have you checked your wamp error logs?
- Have you got the pre-requisites installed, such as the Microsoft VC++ redistributable?

If you're still having trouble, checkout the official forum (such as this post http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,53095) and post there for some decent help.

Comment: I am getting problem at point 2. How to change apache configuration to start? Please help.

Comment: Click the Aestran tray, scroll to Apache, then click httpd.conf, which will open the config file in an editor. What error do you get when you run `httpd -t`?\

Comment: Thanks for response. Now problem is solved. I tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/14550573/1045444.

Answer (score 0):

Migh be the same issue (have to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package) :

[Not able to launch WAMP - Aestan Tray Menu has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631571/not-able-to-launch-wamp/6457092#6457092)

Comment: Nope, issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install .Net framework Latest version.
 Link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21
Before Installing WAMP make sure that you uninstalled old versions.